# To Sir(s): A Grandpa Tribute

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I found this paper on Grandpa's desk. Seemed like a tribute to me. His mediocre poetry notwithstanding, it seemed interesting with many familiar words.

> *To Sir(s)*
>
> Eyes on the target, finger on the gun
>
> Let me tell you again, it was twice as much fun
>
> Kill or die, the end came too soon
>
> Always on top, with view of the moon
>
> It was thunder down under, from no to never
>
> Like gold and diamonds, you live forever
>
> *With Love*

What was this about?  Who was he writing to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grandpa's writings appear to be a tribute to:

> **James Bond**

In particular, it contains a great deal of words which can be found:

> In the titles of particular films (and stories) which feature James Bond. Specifically, where some of the keywords appear in multiple James Bond movie titles there is one (occasionally two) that is more relevant than the others to the final answer...
>  ----------
>  To Sir(s)
>
>  Eyes [*For Your **Eyes** Only*] on the target, finger [*Gold**finger***] on the gun [*The Man with the Golden **Gun***]
>
>  Let [*Live and **Let** Die*] me [*The Spy Who Loved **Me***] tell you again [*Never Say Never **Again***], it was twice [*You Only Live **Twice***] as much fun
>
>  Kill [*A View to a **Kill*** <sub>(most relevant)</sub>] or die [*Live and Let **Die*** <sub>(most relevant)</sub>], the end came too soon
>
>  Always on top [*Oc**top**ussy*], with view [*A **View** to a Kill*] of the moon [***Moon***raker]
>
>  It was thunder [***Thunder***ball] down under, from no [*Dr **No***] to never [***Never*** Say **Never** Again <sub>(most relevant)</sub>]
>
>  Like gold [***Gold***finger / The Man with the **Gold**en Gun <sub>(most relevant)</sub>] and diamonds [***Diamonds*** Are Forever], you live [*You Only **Live** Twice / **Live** and Let Die*] forever [*Diamonds Are **Forever***]
>
>  With Love [*From Russia **With Love***]
>  ----------
>  <sup>*Note that I have ignored the smaller words which appear in titles, such as 'the' and 'to'. Also, note that Never Say Never Again was not technically part of the official James Bond franchise but is more an independent reworking of 1965's Thunderball.*</sup>

Specifically, then, Grandpa is writing to:

> **Sir Sean Connery** and **Sir Roger Moore** - the two *knighted* actors to have portrayed James Bond on film - as the movie titles selected in the piece of writing are all those which starred one or the other of them:
>
>  <sup>Sir Sean Connery - *Dr No* (1962), *From Russia With Love* (1963), *Goldfinger* (1964), *Thunderball* (1965), *You Only Live Twice* (1967), *Diamonds Are Forever* (1971), *Never Say Never Again* (1983);</sup>
>
>  <sup>Sir Roger Moore - *Live and Let Die* (1973), *The Man with the Golden Gun* (1974), *The Spy Who Loved Me* (1977), *Moonraker* (1979), *For Your Eyes Only* (1981), *Octopussy* (1983), *A View to a Kill* (1985).</sup>

This answer makes sense of:

> The opening line, *To Sir(s)*, where 'Sir' is capitalised, just like the title bestowed upon somebody who has been knighted. (See @El-Guest's answer for a nice additional connection between the Bond franchise and the song, "*To Sir with Love*"...) The fact that this letter is written to *two* people also makes sense of the phrase '*it was **twice** as much fun*', and the phrase '*from no to never*' references the first and last films of Sean Connery's time as Bond.

Finally, I hope that this is just an open letter or a piece of poetry that Grandpa has written, and not a piece of actual correspondence to which he is expecting a response...

> Because Sir Roger Moore passed away in 2017!

Comment: To Sir(s)  is pertinent. Look at the films. Jub jrer gur npgbef?

Comment: @DEEM Okay, I have revised my suggested recipient(s) - to almost entirely the opposite in fact!

Comment: Gubfr svyzf jrer ol Fve Frna Pbaarel naq Fve Ebtre Zbber

Comment: @DEEM Ah, right - once I strip out some of the alternatives that can hold. As it stands some of them may be considered to point towards others. I will edit accordingly so it all holds together more firmly... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe @Stiv has nailed most of the references, except

> To Sir, with Love is a famous song by Lulu, a Scottish singer who also sang the title track for The Man With The Golden Gun.

Therefore this is addressed to

> The actor who played James Bond in that film, Sir Roger Moore, CBE (who recently passed three years ago).